# My custom keyboard does not work

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, colemak

I am trying to create a modified version of Colemak inspired by Programmer's Dvorak, but aimed at writing in LaTeX. The current, experimental version is seen below. Like in Programmer's Dvorak, the top keys produce symbols by default, while holding Shift yields numbers. Occasionally, I want to write many numbers and need some kind of Caps Lock for this purpose, but which only affects the top row and does not capitalize the letters. I have placed this Caps Lock on the "tilde" button and assigned the type "Four level" to all characters I do not want affected by this.

However, I have two problems:

First of all, Caps Lock works just right for the symbol row, but still capitalizes alphabetic characters (even if I put my layout on the top of the keyboard list). Secondly, if I try to remove the standard keyboard from the list, I get this lovely message:

> Error activating XKB configuration.
>   There can be various reasons for that.
>
> If you report this situation as a bug, include the results of
>
> - xprop -root | grep XKB
> - gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard model
> - gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard layouts
> - gsettings get org.gnome.libgnomekbd.keyboard options

I have been looking for typing errors for hours. **What am I doing wrong?**

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys

// Colemak symbols for xkb on X.Org Server 7.x
// 2006-01-01 Shai Coleman, http://colemak.com/

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "coltex" {
    include "us"
    name[Group1]= "English (ColTeX)";

    key.type[Group1]="FOUR_LEVEL";

    key <TLDE> { [ Caps_Lock ]};

    key <AE01> { [            bracketleft, grave ] };
    key <AE02> { [            bracketright,           7 ], type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC"  };
    key <AE03> { [            braceleft,   5 ], type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC"  };
    key <AE04> { [            braceright,       3,            threesuperior ], type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC"  };
    key <AE05> { [            parenleft,      1,        onesuperior ], type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC"  };
    key <AE06> { [            ampersand,  9 ], type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC"  };
    key <AE07> { [            percent,    0 ], type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC"  };
    key <AE08> { [            parenright,     2,           twosuperior ], type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC"  };
    key <AE09> { [            plus,    4, EuroSign ], type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC"  };
    key <AE10> { [            minus,   6, sterling ], type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC"  };

    key <AE11> { [        asciicircum, 8 ] };
    key <AE12> { [        numbersign, bar ] };

    key <AD01> { [            q,            Q,      dead_tilde ]};
    key <AD02> { [            w,            W,      dead_circumflex ] };
    key <AD03> { [            f,            F,          dead_grave ] };
    key <AD04> { [            p,            P,          dead_acute ] };
    key <AD05> { [            g,            G,     dead_doubleacute ] };
    key <AD06> { [            j,            J ] };
    key <AD07> { [            l,            L,         leftsinglequotemark  ] };
    key <AD08> { [            u,            U,          rightsinglequotemark ] };
    key <AD09> { [            y,            Y  ] };
    key <AD10> { [       backslash,         exclam  ] };
    key <AD11> { [  equal,    slash ] };
    key <AD12> { [ asterisk, quotedbl   ] };
    key <BKSL> { [    underscore, at  ] };

    key <AC01> { [            a,            A,          eacute,           Eacute ],type[Group1] = "FOUR_LEVEL_ALPHABETIC" };
    key <AC02> { [            r,            R,           aring,            Aring ] };
    key <AC03> { [            s,            S,           oslash,         Ooblique ] };
    key <AC04> { [            t,            T,              ae,               AE ] };
    key <AC05> { [            d,            D, dead_diaeresis ] };
    key <AC06> { [            h,            H ] };
    key <AC07> { [            n,            N,          leftdoublequotemark ] };
    key <AC08> { [            e,            E,          rightdoublequotemark  ] };
    key <AC09> { [            i,            I, guillemotright ] };
    key <AC10> { [            o,            O, guillemotleft  ] };
    key <AC11> { [    dollar,        apostrophe  ] };

    key <AB01> { [            z,            Z, oe, OE ] };
    key <AB02> { [            x,            X,         multiply  ] };
    key <AB03> { [            c,            C,        ccedilla,         Ccedilla ] };
    key <AB04> { [            v,            V,          ssharp ] };
    key <AB05> { [            b,            B ] };
    key <AB06> { [            k,            K  ] };
    key <AB07> { [            m,            M ] };
    key <AB08> { [        comma,         less ] };
    key <AB09> { [       period,      greater  ] };
    key <AB10> { [        semicolon,     colon,    endash,       emdash ] };

    key <CAPS> { [    BackSpace,    BackSpace,       BackSpace,        BackSpace ] };
    key <LSGT> { [        asciitilde,   question, quotedbl,    nobreakspace ] };
    key <SPCE> { [        space,        space,           space,     nobreakspace ] };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```